# Regex to detect repetition

Tags: regex

I need a regex to detect different forms of repetitions (where the entire word is a multiple of same character/substring). The total length of the word should be minimum 7 (of the whole word, not of the repetitive sequence)

Example - Terms as follows are not allowed

```
abcdefabcdef
brian
2222222
john12john12
```

Terms as follows are allowed

```
hellojohn 
2122222222
abcdefabc
```

Comment: There is a lot left to the imagination here. what does "*minimum length 7*" mean, does a repetition mean repetitions that are consecutive only with no other characters in the string. What about `212222222` You need to do more work on this question

Comment: what about `11111222`

Comment: Edited the question, 11111222 is allowed

Comment: Why is `2122222222` allowed?  The repeating part `22222222` is more than 7 characters

Comment: The total length of the word is minimum 7, not of the repeating word

Comment: what about `11221133` allowed ?

Comment: 11221133 is allowed too.

Comment: If a word consists only of multiple occurrences of same sequence, it is not allowed. So 11221122 is not allowed as the term is 2*1122 while 11221133 is allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validity of this answer depends on the regular expression engine you are using, as it uses negative look-aheads to effectively "invert" the repeated substring matching. You can play with the regex solution here: https://regex101.com/r/DjmuaI/1/

**Short answer**: `^(?!(.+?)\1+).{7,}$`

**Long answer**:

- Start off by trying to match at least one repetition of a character sequence. This tries to capture a sequence of characters `(.+)` and uses a back-reference of this captured group `\1`. 
  `^(.+)\1$`
- Allow more than 1 repetition by adding `+` to our capture group back-reference. This now detects a character sequence that is a substring repeated. 
  `^(.+)\1+$`
- Look for character sequences that are NOT repeating. A negative-lookahead `(?!regex)` (which support varies between regex engines) allows us to invert the condition. 
  `^(?!(.+?)\1+).+$`
- However, this would match any non-repetitive string (including strings less than 7 in length). The pattern can be changed to be 7 or more characters using `{7,}`.
  `^(?!(.+?)\1+).{7,}$`

I will note that matching some strings may be not have great performance.